# How to obtain an approximately square multiline UILabel using Autolayout

Tags: ios, autolayout, uilabel

I'm putting a multiline UILabel into a popup. The text has a variable length. What I'd really like to do is get a size that is approximately square—so that when displayed it has a nice appearance.

If I create a constraint that sets the label width to equal the height, I get a one line label with a matching height.

There is a (IMHO a terrible) solution: get the width of the one line label, then in a loop set a width constraint to an ever decreasing a fraction of the original width, layout, then stop when the label bound's is more or less what's desired.

Surely there is a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any way to do this *without* looping through sizes.

I can't quite work out what you're doing in the code in your answer -- couldn't get it to produce the expected results. However...

First, instead of setting constraints and forcing auto-layout passes, we can take advantage of `systemLayoutSizeFitting` ([Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622624-systemlayoutsizefitting)). For example:

```
    let v = UILabel()
    v.numberOfLines = 0
    v.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 16.0, weight: .regular)
    
    // set the label's text
    v.text = "An Example String: The quick red fox jumps over the lazy brown dog."
    
    // get the widest size
    let sz = v.systemLayoutSizeFitting(.init(width: .greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: 1.0))

    print("Size:", sz)
    
    // prints "Size: (497.0, 19.333333333333332)"
```

That gives us the width and height of the string as a single line. Well, not really... if the string has embedded newline characters:

```
"An Example String:\n\nThe quick red fox jumps over the lazy brown dog."
```

Its "native" layout will be:

```
An Example String:

The quick red fox jumps over the lazy brown dog.
```

So that same line of code:

```
    let sz = v.systemLayoutSizeFitting(.init(width: .greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: 1.0))

    // prints "Size: (355.6666666666667, 57.333333333333336)"
```

Which ***is*** what we want.

So, let's change the `width` to one-half of the non-constrained width (we'll remove the newline chars):

```
    v.text = "An Example String: The quick red fox jumps over the lazy brown dog."
    
    var sz = v.systemLayoutSizeFitting(.init(width: .greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: 1.0))
    print("Size:", sz)
    
    sz = v.systemLayoutSizeFitting(.init(width: sz.width * 0.5, height: 1.0))
    print("Size:", sz)

    // prints "Size: (497.0, 19.333333333333332)"
    // prints "Size: (244.66666666666666, 57.333333333333336)"
```

Now, a ratio can be expressed as a decimal value with `width / height`.

For example, `5:3` is `5.0 / 3.0 = 1.666...`

With the above two resulting sizes, we get:

```
Size: (497.0, 19.333333333333332)
Ratio: 497.0 / 19.333 = 25.70689655172414
AKA:   5.0 : 0.195

Size: (244.66666666666666, 57.333333333333336)
Ratio: 244.666 / 57.333 = 4.267441860465116
AKA:   5.0 : 1.172
```

If we want to find the "optimal" dimensions for a given aspect ratio, we can loop through, dividing the width in half each time, and compare the result:

```
    // we want a 5:3 result
    let targetWidth: CGFloat = 5.0
    let targetHeight: CGFloat = 3.0
    let targetRatio: CGFloat = targetWidth / targetHeight
    
    print("Target Ratio:", targetRatio)
    print("AKA:         ", String(format: "%0.1f : %0.3f", targetWidth, targetHeight))

    var sz = v.systemLayoutSizeFitting(.init(width: .greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: 1.0))

    while (sz.width / sz.height) > targetRatio {

        print()
        print("New Size:", sz)
        print("New Ratio:", sz.width / sz.height)
        print("AKA:      ", String(format: "%0.1f : %0.3f", targetWidth, sz.height / (sz.width / targetWidth)))

        // cut the Width in half
        // get the new Size contstrained to Width
        sz = v.systemLayoutSizeFitting(.init(width: sz.width * 0.5, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude))
        
    }

    print()
    print("We now have a smaller ratio than targetRatio")
    print("New Size:", sz)
    print("New Ratio:", sz.width / sz.height)
    print("AKA:      ", String(format: "%0.1f : %0.3f", targetWidth, sz.height / (sz.width / targetWidth)))
```

and the console output will be:

```
Target Ratio: 1.6666666666666667
AKA:          5.0 : 3.000

New Size: (497.0, 19.333333333333332)
New Ratio: 25.70689655172414
AKA:       5.0 : 0.195

New Size: (244.66666666666666, 57.333333333333336)
New Ratio: 4.267441860465116
AKA:       5.0 : 1.172

We now have a smaller ratio than targetRatio
New Size: (115.0, 95.66666666666667)
New Ratio: 1.2020905923344947
AKA:       5.0 : 4.159
```

The visualization of that looks like this:

[image]

The final ratio of `5.0 : 4.159` isn't very close to `5 : 3` though, and there's a big gap between that and the previous `5.0 : 1.172` ratio... and we can get much closer with this size:

[image]

We *could* simply "brute force" it, adding another loop increasing the width by `1.0` each time, until we get closer to the target ratio. But, that would be inefficient... and potentially a lot of loops.

So one approach would be to evaluate the size/ratio changes using effectively a binary search pattern, increasing or decreasing the width by one-half of the previous gap, until we find our "optimal" size.

Here's an example function:

```
func sizeForOptimalDimension(label: UILabel, targetWidth: CGFloat, targetHeight: CGFloat) -> (CGSize, CGSize)? {
    
    guard let str = label.text, !str.isEmpty else { return nil }
    
    let targetRatio: CGFloat = targetWidth / targetHeight
    
    var curWidth: CGFloat = 0
    var curSize: CGSize = .zero
    var lastSize: CGSize = .zero
    var prevDiff: CGFloat = 0
    var wInc: CGFloat = 0
    
    // create a new label for calculations
    let v = UILabel()
    v.numberOfLines = 0
    v.font = label.font
    
    // set the label's text
    v.text = str
    
    // get the widest size (single-line height)
    curSize = v.systemLayoutSizeFitting(.init(width: .greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: font.lineHeight + 1.0))
    
    curWidth = curSize.width
    
    // if currentRatio is less than targetRatio to begin with,
    // for example, a string with embedded newlines
    // such as: ""One\nTwo\nThree"
    //  -------
    //  One
    //  Two
    //  Three
    //  Four
    //  Five
    //  -------
    // we can't do anything to it (and we'd get an infinite loop)
    if (curSize.width / curSize.height) < targetRatio {
        lastSize = curSize
    } else {
        
        prevDiff = curWidth
        
        // while the calculated Ratio is Greater-Than the targetRatio
        while (curSize.width / curSize.height) > targetRatio {
            
            // cut the Width in half
            curWidth *= 0.5
            // get the new Size contstrained to Width
            curSize = v.systemLayoutSizeFitting(.init(width: curWidth, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude))
            
            prevDiff -= curWidth
            
        }
        
        // we now have a smaller ratio than targetRatio
        lastSize = curSize
        
        curWidth = curSize.width
        
        // we'll start incrementing by one-half of the last difference
        wInc = floor(prevDiff * 0.5)
        
        // this should always be true
        //  but sanity check to avoid an infinite loop
        if (curSize.width / curSize.height) < targetRatio {
            
            // while the calculated Ratio is Less-Than the targetRatio
            while (curSize.width / curSize.height) < targetRatio {
                
                // save the current size
                lastSize = curSize
                
                // increment Width
                curWidth += wInc
                
                // get the new Size contstrained to Width
                curSize = v.systemLayoutSizeFitting(.init(width: curWidth, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude))
                
                // if the new ratio is again Greater than the targetRatio
                //  AND the increment is Greater than 1
                if (curSize.width / curSize.height) > targetRatio && wInc > 1.0 {
                    //  reset the current width
                    //  reset the current size
                    //  cut the increment in half
                    curWidth -= wInc
                    curSize = lastSize
                    wInc = floor(wInc * 0.5)
                }
                
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    
    return (lastSize, curSize)
    
}
```

You'll notice that function returns **two** sizes -- the closest size smaller and the closest size larger than the target ratio. This will be most noticeable with shorter strings. For example:

[image]

Neither resulting ratio -- `5.0:5.059` or `5.0:1.917` -- is particularly close to `5.0:3.0`. So, depending on your overall layout goal, you could choose "closest to target ratio" or "prefer wider" for example.

Here is a complete view controller class to try out:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    // target ratio
    let targetWidth: CGFloat = 5.0
    let targetHeight: CGFloat = 3.0
    
    let font: UIFont = .systemFont(ofSize: 16.0, weight: .regular)
    
    let labelA: UILabel = UILabel()
    let labelB: UILabel = UILabel()
    let labelC: UILabel = UILabel()
    
    var labelAWidth: NSLayoutConstraint!
    var labelBWidth: NSLayoutConstraint!
    var labelCWidth: NSLayoutConstraint!
    
    let infoA: UILabel = UILabel()
    let infoB: UILabel = UILabel()
    let infoC: UILabel = UILabel()
    
    var samples: [String] = [
        "An Example String: The quick red fox jumps over the lazy brown dog.",
        "Short string to use in testing.",
        "UILabel: A label can contain an arbitrary amount of text, but UILabel may shrink, wrap, or truncate the text, depending on the size of the bounding rectangle and properties you set. You can control the font, text color, alignment, highlighting, and shadowing of the text in the label.",
        "UIButton: Displays a plain styled button that can have a title, subtitle, image, and other appearance properties.",
        "UIViewController: Provides view-management functionality for toolbars, navigation bars, and application views. The UIViewController class also supports modal views and rotating views when device orientation changes.",
        "Linefeeds:\n\nNote that this also works with strings that contain embedded linefeed characters.",
        // this will break UICollectionViewFlowLayoutInvalidationContext onto multiple lines
        "But, if we have a very long word, such as UICollectionViewFlowLayoutInvalidationContext, word-wrapping is an issue.",
        // this will be tall and very narrow, so we can't do anything with it
        "And\nwe\ncannot\ndo\nanything\nwith\nthis.",
    ]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        [infoA, infoB, infoC].forEach { v in
            v.numberOfLines = 0
            v.textAlignment = .center
            v.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 14.0, weight: .light)
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.addSubview(v)
        }
        
        [labelA, labelB, labelC].forEach { v in
            v.numberOfLines = 0
            v.font = font
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.addSubview(v)
        }
        
        labelA.backgroundColor = .cyan
        labelB.backgroundColor = .green
        labelC.backgroundColor = .yellow
        
        // these will be set later
        labelAWidth = labelA.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100.0)
        labelBWidth = labelB.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100.0)
        labelCWidth = labelC.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100.0)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            infoA.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            infoA.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            labelA.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: infoA.bottomAnchor, constant: 2.0),
            labelA.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            infoB.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: labelA.bottomAnchor, constant: 16.0),
            infoB.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            labelB.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: infoB.bottomAnchor, constant: 2.0),
            labelB.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            infoC.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: labelB.bottomAnchor, constant: 16.0),
            infoC.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            labelC.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: infoC.bottomAnchor, constant: 2.0),
            labelC.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            labelAWidth, labelBWidth, labelCWidth,
        ])
        
        nextString()
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        nextString()
    }
    
    func nextString() {
        
        // cycle to the next sample string
        let str = samples.removeFirst()
        samples.append(str)
        
        [labelA, labelB, labelC].forEach { v in
            v.text = str
        }
        
        updateLabels()
        
    }
    
    func updateLabels() {
        
        var lastSize: CGSize = .zero
        var curSize: CGSize = .zero
        (lastSize, curSize) = sizeForOptimalDimension(label: labelA, targetWidth: targetWidth, targetHeight: targetHeight) ?? (.zero, .zero)
        
        // get the ratios of the last smaller and last larger calculated sizes
        let lastRatio: CGFloat = lastSize.width / lastSize.height
        let curRatio: CGFloat = curSize.width / curSize.height
        
        let targetRatio: CGFloat = targetWidth / targetHeight
        
        let lastDiff: CGFloat = abs(targetRatio - lastRatio)
        let curDiff: CGFloat = abs(targetRatio - curRatio)
        
        // which new ratio is closest to targetRatio?
        let finalSize: CGSize = curDiff < lastDiff ? curSize : lastSize
        
        var w: CGFloat = 0
        var h: CGFloat = 0
        var r: CGFloat = 0
        
        w = lastSize.width
        h = lastSize.height
        r = h / (w / targetWidth)
        
        let lastR: String = String(format: "%0.1f:%0.3f", targetWidth, r)
        
        w = curSize.width
        h = curSize.height
        r = h / (w / targetWidth)
        
        let curR: String = String(format: "%0.1f:%0.3f", targetWidth, r)
        
        w = finalSize.width
        h = finalSize.height
        r = h / (w / targetWidth)
        
        let finalR: String = String(format: "%0.1f:%0.3f", targetWidth, r)
        
        // update the width constraints
        labelAWidth.constant = lastSize.width
        labelBWidth.constant = curSize.width
        labelCWidth.constant = finalSize.width
        
        let infoStrings: [String] = [
            String(format: "%0.3f x %0.3f = Ratio \(lastR)", lastSize.width, lastSize.height),
            String(format: "%0.3f x %0.3f = Ratio \(curR)", curSize.width, curSize.height),
            String(format: "Closest to %0.1f x %0.1f\n%0.3f x %0.3f = Ratio \(finalR)", targetWidth, targetHeight, curSize.width, curSize.height),
        ]
        for (s, v) in zip(infoStrings, [infoA, infoB, infoC]) {
            v.text = s
        }
        
    }
    
    func sizeForOptimalDimension(label: UILabel, targetWidth: CGFloat, targetHeight: CGFloat) -> (CGSize, CGSize)? {
        
        guard let str = label.text, !str.isEmpty else { return nil }
        
        let targetRatio: CGFloat = targetWidth / targetHeight
        
        var curWidth: CGFloat = 0
        var curSize: CGSize = .zero
        var lastSize: CGSize = .zero
        var prevDiff: CGFloat = 0
        var wInc: CGFloat = 0
        
        // create a new label for calculations
        let v = UILabel()
        v.numberOfLines = 0
        v.font = label.font
        
        // set the label's text
        v.text = str
        
        // get the widest size (single-line height)
        curSize = v.systemLayoutSizeFitting(.init(width: .greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: font.lineHeight + 1.0))
        
        curWidth = curSize.width
        
        // if currentRatio is less than targetRatio to begin with,
        // for example, a string with embedded newlines
        // such as: ""One\nTwo\nThree"
        //  -------
        //  One
        //  Two
        //  Three
        //  Four
        //  Five
        //  -------
        // we can't do anything to it (and we'd get an infinite loop)
        if (curSize.width / curSize.height) < targetRatio {
            lastSize = curSize
        } else {
            
            prevDiff = curWidth
            
            // while the calculated Ratio is Greater-Than the targetRatio
            while (curSize.width / curSize.height) > targetRatio {
                
                // cut the Width in half
                curWidth *= 0.5
                // get the new Size contstrained to Width
                curSize = v.systemLayoutSizeFitting(.init(width: curWidth, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude))
                
                prevDiff -= curWidth
                
            }
            
            // we now have a smaller ratio than targetRatio
            lastSize = curSize
            
            curWidth = curSize.width
            
            // we'll start incrementing by one-half of the last difference
            wInc = floor(prevDiff * 0.5)
            
            // this should always be true
            //  but sanity check to avoid an infinite loop
            if (curSize.width / curSize.height) < targetRatio {
                
                // while the calculated Ratio is Less-Than the targetRatio
                while (curSize.width / curSize.height) < targetRatio {
                    
                    // save the current size
                    lastSize = curSize
                    
                    // increment Width
                    curWidth += wInc
                    
                    // get the new Size contstrained to Width
                    curSize = v.systemLayoutSizeFitting(.init(width: curWidth, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude))
                    
                    // if the new ratio is again Greater than the targetRatio
                    //  AND the increment is Greater than 1
                    if (curSize.width / curSize.height) > targetRatio && wInc > 1.0 {
                        //  reset the current width
                        //  reset the current size
                        //  cut the increment in half
                        curWidth -= wInc
                        curSize = lastSize
                        wInc = floor(wInc * 0.5)
                    }
                    
                }
                
            }
            
        }
        
        return (lastSize, curSize)
        
    }
    
}
```

Tapping anywhere will cycle through the sample strings array:

[image]

[image]

[image]

There will be some "edge cases" that can cause issues... One is when you have a very long word - such as **UICollectionViewFlowLayoutInvalidationContext** - that can result in quirky word-wrapping:

[image]

The other case is when the "native" layout **cannot** be modified to fit the target ratio - such as this string: `"And\nwe\ncannot\ndo\nanything\nwith\nthis."` which gives us this result:

[image]

This is just *one possible approach* - but maybe it can help you out. Please keep in mind: this is ***EXAMPLE CODE ONLY!!!***. I didn't spend much time on it... the "fit algorithm" could likely be improved, and I'm sure there are some edge cases that would need some additional error handling.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, here is my current solution:

```
let label = UILabel()
label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
label.text = "... your text..."
label.textAlignment = .left
label.numberOfLines = 0
label.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = false
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = false
label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping

// to dynamically resize, the label must be installed in some view that has a window property
view.addSubview(label)
constrainToOptimalDimension(label: label)
label.removeFromSuperview()   private func constrainToOptimalDimension(label: UILabel) {
// label now has a width constraint that forces a landscape picture frame orientation


private func constrainToOptimalDimension(label: UILabel) {
   label.sizeToFit()
   let oneLineWidth = Int(label.bounds.size.width)

    var optimalWidth = oneLineWidth
    for i in 2..<10 {
        label.snp.remakeConstraints { make in
            make.width.equalTo(oneLineWidth/i) // .multipliedBy(0.66)
        }
        label.setNeedsLayout()
        label.layoutIfNeeded()
        // my goal - a picture frame width of 5 height 3
        if label.bounds.size.height * 5 > label.bounds.size.width * 3 {
            optimalWidth = oneLineWidth/(i - 1)
            break
        }
    }
    // using SnapKit, but you can use any contraint engine you want
    label.snp.remakeConstraints { make in
        make.width.equalTo(optimalWidth) // .multipliedBy(0.66)
    }
    label.setNeedsLayout()
    return
}
```